# Can't iterate over children's children because of the subsequent .clear()?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, iterparse

I'm trying to use the pattern described in the ["event-driven parsing"](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing) section of the `lxml` tutorial.

In my code I'm calling a function that can recursively run on elements using the `iterchildren()` method. I'll just use two nested loop for illustration here.

This works as expected:

```py
xml = StringIO("<root><a><b>data</b><c><d/></c></a><a><z/></a></root>")
for ev, elem in etree.iterparse(xml):
    if elem.tag == 'a':
        for c in elem.iterchildren():
             for gc in c.iterchildren():
                  print gc
```

The output is `<Element d at 0x2df49b0>`.

But if I add `.clear()` in the end:

```py
for ev, elem in etree.iterparse(xml):
    if elem.tag == 'a':
        for c in elem.iterchildren():
             for gc in c.iterchildren():
                  print gc
    elem.clear()
```

-- it doesn't print anything. Why is it so and what do I do to work around this?

Notes:

- I can skip `iterchildren` and do `for c in elem` or `for c in list(elem)`, with the same effect.
- I need to use iterative approach to keep the memory usage low.
- In the real use case, I am doing an element lookup using an attribute:

  ```py
  if elem.attrib.get('id') == elem_id:
      return _get_info(elem)
  ```

I would like an explanation of how `clear` manages to erase the inner elements before they are processed, and how to keep them in memory while they're needed for processing of the ancestors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `iterparse` by default yields `end` events. For subelements `end` events are generated earlier than for their ancestors:

```py
>>> for ev, elem in etree.iterparse(xml):
       print elem

<Element b at 0x38fe320>
<Element d at 0x38fe0f0>
<Element c at 0x38fe2d0>
<Element a at 0x38fe190>
<Element z at 0x38fe230>
<Element a at 0x38fe3c0>
<Element root at 0x2df48c0>
```

In this simple case the problem can be solved by relying on the `start` events instead:

```py
for ev, elem in etree.iterparse(xml, events=('start',)):
    ...
```

However, the linked docs say,

> Note that the text, tail and children of an Element are not
>   necessarily there yet when receiving the start event. Only the end
>   event guarantees that the Element has been parsed completely.

That probably means that both `start` and `end` events should be processed to allow calling `clear()` only when it's safe. I'm thinking of implementing some kind of a stack and pushing things there on `start` events, popping and `clear`ing on `end`  events.

I would very much welcome answers that show implementations using this or other ideas.

**Note**: the easiest thing to do is just indent the `clear` call into the `if`. That would allow accessing grandchildren, but all unrelated elements would remain un`clear`ed.

---

**EDIT**

I am currently using a state-keeping variable in the following manner:

```py
found = False
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(source, events=('start', 'end')):
    if event == 'start':
        if elem.attrib.get('id') == elem_id:
            found = True
    else:
        if elem.attrib.get('id') == elem_id:
            return _get_info(elem)
        if not found:
            elem.clear()
```